# Missing characters Special characters in e-mail when using extended mail umbraco

Tags: umbraco, contour, umbraco-contour

I have a problem with German characters when using the type "Send email, extened".
i recieve mail the character set is all messed up.
Example :
Müler ==> M??ler

help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a character set encoding issue with the way that the email is being encoded. The default encoding for emails in ASP.Net is us-ascii which will be missing the extra characters. Report the issue to the Contour guys at [the Umbraco Issues tracker](http://issues.umbraco.org/issues/CON) and they should fix it. If you're in a hurry, just write your own send email workflow, ensuring that the email uses the correct encoding for the character set that you are using (such as UTF8). For information on how to create your own workflows, refer to the Contour developers guide, which has an example. You can see the source code of most of the built in Workflows [here](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-contour-shared-source)